# Create a permanent list of a content type

Tags: input-formats

I have a content type named "clients" which can be filtered within a view and all can be selected using bulk operations.

What I would like to do is take the filtered list in the view and copy it to a permanent list of content on my site. So that it is saved and can be accessed at a later date without having to go through the filter options again.

For example, to store a list of clients all from one country, say Germany, to a list of these clients named Germany.

Any ideas how I would do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Views Save](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_save) module can help you. The module page says

> This projects allows admins to add a "Save" button to their views (on
>   a per-view basis). This button allows logged-in visitors to save their
>   current exposed filter settings on the site, so they can later return
>   to the same page. The saved views are stored per user, and can be
>   listed with Views themselves, to provide users with an overview of all
>   their saved views. Saved views can also be overwritten with new
>   settings.
>
> Anonymous users are offered a way to log in or register when trying to
>   save a view – if they do, the view is saved to their (possibly new)
>   account, otherwise it is purged after a while.